# Latex stopped showing text on PDF after some point in the code (Texmaker)

Tags: texmaker

It is my first experience on latex. The code was working well till the I itemized, but after that whatever i enter it doesn't show in pdf.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[toc, page, header]{appendix} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[plain]{fancyref} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}
\author{Mohammad Bilal}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\title{hello}
\maketitle
\let\cleardoublepage\relax 
\let\clearpage\relax
\begin{flushleft}
\chapter {Introduction}
\section {Intrdodution}
\subsection {Background Information}

\end{flushleft}
\subsection {Application}
\subsection {Known Knowledge}
\subsection {Problem}

\section{Research motives}
\section{Objectives}
\section{Structure of thesis }
\chapter{Literature Review}
\section{Laboratory tests}
\subsection{Uniaxial Compression test }
\subsection{Brazilian tensile test}
\section{Relevant Rock Mechanics}


\section{Cracking process}
\subsection{Characteristics}
\subsection{aaaaa}
\subsection{Crack propagation}
\subsection{Quantification}
\section{techniques}

\section{Numerical techniques}
The most commonly applied numerical methods 

\begin{itemize}
\item Continuum methods
\item Discrete methods 
\item Hybrid
\end{itemize}
% Code stops working from here and I see the pdf genrated till the above line
\subsection{methods}
\subsection{ methods}
\section{FEM}
\section{FDEM}
\section{ Method }
\subsection{Background}
\subsection{Theory}
\subsection{Models}
\section{Calibration}
\subsection{Uniaxial Test}
\subsection{Brazilian test}


\bibliography{library} 
\bibliographystyle{Apalike}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You've redefined the commands `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` in lines 18 and 19, which is why everything seems to run off the page and disappear. Remove those lines, and everything should typeset fine.

Comment: thanks, that works well but it leaves a blank page after the title page (this was the reason I used the clear page command initially).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the lines `\let\cleardoublepage\relax` and `\let\clearpage\relax` make it difficult (impossible) for `LaTeX` to declare new pages; I strongly advise against redefining such basic commands. To remove the extra page after your title page, don't use the `flushleft` environment. Everything is already flush left by default. So instead of this part of your code:

```
\title{hello}
\maketitle
\let\cleardoublepage\relax 
\let\clearpage\relax
\begin{flushleft}
\chapter {Introduction}
\section {Intrdodution}
\subsection {Background Information}

\end{flushleft}
\subsection {Application}
\subsection {Known Knowledge}
\subsection {Problem}
```

You should have this in your code:

```
\title{hello}
\maketitle
\chapter {Introduction}
\section {Intrdodution}
\subsection {Background Information}

\subsection {Application}
\subsection {Known Knowledge}
\subsection {Problem}
```

Comment: Works perfectly well. Thanks a lot Jānis